# Update a textView in real time (using a for)

Tags: java, android, for-loop, android-studio

So I have an android app where I want to decrement a value and display it in a textview. I start from 1000 and decrement it by 1 from 1 to 1 seconds. This acts as a score that decreases in time if you stay more on the level. This is my code:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.game);
    timeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);



    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            for(time=1000;time>=0;time--){
                try {
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                            timeText.setText(String.valueOf(time));
                            System.out.println(time);

                }


                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    System.out.println("Error on delay");
                }

            }}
        });

 }
```

My error is that whenever I enter this activity, the screen turns black. The console is printing the values from second to second and if i comment the "for" the textView displays properly the value 1000 (if i declare int time = 1000 of course). I am really not sure what the problem is here. Does somebody know what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: why are you making thread sleep, it's the main cause and reason for black screen. Try to use Handler instead with recursive postdelay

Comment: Use a timer instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are pausing the UI in that for loop.

To achieve what you want, either use a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //update textview here
        }
    },1000);
```

OR

use a [Timer](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwid2KfMx6DLAhWRGY4KHXniBIoQFggdMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Freference%2Fjava%2Futil%2FTimer.html&usg=AFQjCNFOmQV7mTFhVw9N9MnENAeP3Sf1mA&sig2=egRnzGqURC7Z5_jQt3gs0g)

```
new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //update
        }
    },1000,0);
```

I don't know much about handlers but you don't need a for loop in timer.

In your case:

```
  long time=1000;

  new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                 timeText.setText(String.valueOf(time))
                 time--;
            });
        }
    },1000,0).start();
```

Good luck

Comment: so how exactly should the code using a timer update the thread? also do i have to use the timer inside the UI thread or outside it (i'm guessing inside)?

Comment: you can start the timer inside another thread. Just put the setText() method in runOnUiThread() in the timer's run(). 
And don't forget to call start() on the timer

Comment: it seems like it's still crashing the app, although now i get a direct crash. do you mind sending me the code to what you meant?

Comment: thanks. did that, but it still gave me an error. i created a new Thread and it worked. thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can't just loop on the UI thread like that.  Inside Android there's a message loop on the UI thread.  When it needs to draw, it sends a message to that message loop.  Until you process that message the changes won't appear on screen.  And to process a message, your code must finish and return to the message loop.

If you want to do this, you can't use a for loop on the UI thread.  You need to send individual messages to a Handler for each draw you want to make.